# Jekyll – Check if page belongs to a collection

Tags: collections, jekyll, liquid

Is there a way to check if a current page belongs to a collection? If so, can I check what’s the label of the collection?

Background story: 
What I’m trying to achieve is to display a different layout for all pages that belong to a collection. With this new layout I want to display a side navigation (some sort of „See also”) with listing of all pages in the collection that the current site belongs to.

In case my question turns out to be dumb – forgive me, I’m new to jekyll and I really tried to find out the answer by myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`page.collection` returns the label of the collection to which the document belongs. So I guess you want to do something like:

```
{% if page.collection == 'COLLECTION_LABEL' %}
NEW LAYOUT
{% else %}
OLD LAYOUT
{% endif %}
```

To access the pages in a collection, you can use the label with `site.COLLECTION_LABEL` or `site[COLLECTION_LABEL]` (you need `[]` if it is a variable). Something like:

```
{% for page in site[page.collection] %}
<a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry, to access the collection you need to do `site[page.collection]` as `page.collection` is just the label. I have just updated the answer

Comment: Collection's document's layout cannot be defined from liquid logic. Provided code can only deal with includes.

Comment: @DavidJacquel I am not sure what you mean, can you please elaborate?

Comment: To set a layout, you can do it in document's front matter or in default configuration.
A layout cannot be set from document's content.
You cannot say `{% assign page.layout = 'my_layout' %}` because the page object is **frozen**, it cannot be changed.  
What your code can do, is conditionally use an include :

`{% if page.collection == 'toto' %}
      {% include inc_1.html %}
    {% else %}
      {% include inc_2.html %}
    {% endif %}`

Although, your answer can do the trick, it's not addressing the layout question.

Answer (score 3):

Any collection document has a `page.collection` variable which is the collection label.

But, if you want to associate a specific layout to a collection, you can use [default configuration](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) :

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      type: mycollection
    values:
      layout: a_custom_layout
      anyvar: a_custom_var
```