# How do I access a collection field defined in _config.yml?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

As outlined in Jekyll's [Collections docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/), I've added an additional field to my collections. Here's part of my `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  algebra1-2:
    title: Algebra 1-2
    output: true
```

**How can I access the `title` field in pages and layouts?**

I've tried `{{ page.collection.title }}` (and a dozen other permutations) with no luck. However, I have found that `{{ page.collection }}` will render `algebra1-2`.

**Edit:** I'm not checking whether or not the page belongs to the collection, and also am trying to avoid conditionals and looping over all pages, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53943386/3292279) recommends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jekyll – Check if page belongs to a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53923035/jekyll-check-if-page-belongs-to-a-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this is possible using the following syntax: `{{ site.collections[1].<field> }}`.

So, given the example above, `{{ site.collections[1].title }}` will evaluate to `Algebra 1-2`.